# How to change body based on part of prefix in Atom.io snippets?

Tags: editor, text-editor, atom-editor

I need to make snippets, that body is based on prefix.
I need to do something like

```
d>Hello
```

Will result in

```
def Hello(): pass
```

And for example

```
d>Hi
```

Will result in

```
def Hi(): pass
```

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create snippet with tab stops. When you press <kbd>Tab</kbd> it will go to the first tab stop and let you type in function name or something else. Pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> will cycle through tab stops.

To create the tab stop you have to use `${1}`. If you want your tab stop to have default value you can use `${1:default}`. You just need to replace 1 with corresponding number. For example:

```
'.source.python':
  'Recursive function':
    'prefix': 'rfunc'
    'body': '''
                def ${1:name}(${2}):
                  ${3:#comment}
                  ${1:name}()
            '''
```

will generate this:

```
def name():
  #comment
  name()
```

And will select `name` so that you can replace it. Pressing tab will go between parenthesis and pressing it once again will select `#comment`.

Note that it'll change both occurrences of `name` at once.

Following your example it would be:

```
'.source.python':
  'Function':
    'prefix': 'd'
    'body': 'def ${1:fname}(${2}): ${3:pass}'
```

You can read more about snippets in [Atom's Flight Manual](http://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/snippets/)

Comment: I did the same but i though i could change name directly from snippet. Never mind, thank you.